# PSD to Xcode for iOS

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mobile, iphone

I am a developer and I have been given a couple of psd files to make a couple of screens for an app.

Is there any free way to convert these psd files to something usable in Xcode for iOS Development?

Comment: You put `adobe-photoshop` in the tags. Do you have photoshop or are you actually looking for alternative methods/applications? ...and do you need to convert the whole psd file to another format or do you want to extract assets from it?

Comment: An iOS developer will need .png, and "intelligent" cut images.

Comment: @Joonas I need to extract assets from it. However, I went back to my client to get their designer to extract files for use in Xcode.